# MySQL sum of hours between multiple dates

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have two tables `projects` and `project_hours`, with a one to many (one project, many hours).

Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
    `project_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `project_name` char(50) NOT NULL,
    `project_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`project_id`),
    KEY `project_owner` (`client_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `projects_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`client_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `project_hours` (
    `hours_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `project_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `start_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `end_time` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`hours_id`),
    KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `project_hours_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`project_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I would like to do is select all projects, and get a sum of the hours, so I have a final list of project with total hours. So if I have 1 projects, 2 records in project_hours, I would like to get 1 rows back, and not 2 rows.

Here is what I have tried. What I get is 2 rows, and each one's time span is less than 1 hour, so current_hours is showing as `0`. What can I do to sum the two rows up? to get 1.50 or something along those lines?

```
select *, datediff(start_time, end_time) * 60 as current_hours from projects 
left join project_hours using(project_id)
where client_id = 2
```

Comment: datediff returns a different in days. your query will never work as is, because `some_number_of_days * 60` is **NOT** hours.

Comment: haha, yeah I just realized that.

Comment: I think I found an answer though

Answer (score 0):

Here we go! This seems to do what I was looking for:

```
select *, sum(time_to_sec(timediff(end_time, start_time))) / 60 / 60 as current_hours from projects 
left join project_hours using(project_id)
where client_id = 2
group by project_id
```